# NestJs jwt auth global guards TypeError: Cannot read property 'secretOrKeyProvider' of undefined

Tags: typescript, authentication, jwt, nestjs

I am using global filters as below.

```
const server = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
server.useGlobalGuards(new (AuthGuard('jwt')));
```

My applicationmodule looks like below.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtModule, JwtModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { AppController } from './application.controller';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigType } from '@nestjs/config';
import jwtConfig from './config/jwt.config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forFeature(jwtConfig),
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule.forFeature(jwtConfig)],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigType<typeof jwtConfig>) => {
        return {
          secret: config.secretKey,
          signOptions: { expiresIn: config.expiresIn },
        } as JwtModuleOptions;
      },
      inject: [jwtConfig.KEY],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController
  ],
  providers: [Strategy],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

and I am getting below error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'secretOrKeyProvider' of undefined
```

What am I missing? I am unable to find any example where Global auth guards are used.

Comment: can u show us the whole stack trace?

Comment: Where is your strategy?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Hey man. You are angel. I actually referred some code where it was directly used from import { Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';

But after your comment, I realized that implementation of that might be required (I had seen in some code, just didn't know if that was required as other places were implementing above way).

I have implemented strategy and now I am not getting an error. You can post answer using below code. :)

Comment: @Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: "process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY",
    });
  }
}

Comment: and used it in module as below. and it worked.

providers: [JwtStrategy, UserService],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JwtStrategy` (or some other passport strategy class) needs to be created. This logic is different per server/application, so it's impossible to say what generally. The [Nest docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-passport-jwt) do a good job of showing an example.